# JPA PrimaryKeyJoinColumn Compound id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, entity

I have a problem with the mapping in JPA of this situation:

[image: An employee with multiple address]

The table Address has as primary key a compound key :

- a code address (home, work, second home)
- the id of employee as foreign key

I want report this situation with JPA:

```java
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_EMPLOYEE")
    private int id_employee;
    
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name
    
    ??join???
}
    
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_EMPLOYEE")
    private int id_employee;
    
    @Column(name="COD_ADDRESS")
    private int cod_address;
    
    @Column(name="STREET")
    private String street
    
    ??join???
}
```

I used `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` with `OneToOne` case but, I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me?

Comment: You've got a few errors in what you've posted for Address - I'd suggest you make an Address.employee property that uses the ID_EMPLOYEE as a fk (join column), so you can have it auto set when you reference an employee - it is an immutable FK anyway. You then need to mark it And the cod_address with the ID annotation (see numerous articles on JPA derived and composite IDs, but you just need an ID class for use in find operations). From Employee, it is then just a OneToMany that is mapped by the address.employee relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to show in code I guess:

```
@Entity
public class Employee{
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID_EMPLOYEE")
  private int id_employee;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String name

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
  private List<Address> Addresses;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AddressId.class)
public class Address{
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="ID_EMPLOYEE")
  private employee employee;

  @Id
  @Column(name="COD_ADDRESS")//fixed the column name
  private int cod_address;//wouldn't you want to use an ENUM?

  @Column(name="STREET")
  private String street

}

public class AddressId{
  public int employee;//same as the id in Employee
  public int cod_address;
}
```

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
  private List<Email> emails;
Do you mean:
 List<Address> addresses 
?

Comment: OK I tried your suggest: I have created AddressId that implemente Serializable, I have inserted hashCode, equals, default constructor and I have inserted in the annotation @IdClass(AddressId.class) on Address but eclipse mark the annotation with error:
"The primary key attribute "addresses" does not have a matching ID class attribute"

Comment: I don't quite understand what you have - where is there an 'address' that is a primary key attribute? The only 'addresses' property would be in Employee and it isn't an ID or related to a composite ID at all. Maybe show the error and what you now have.

Comment: It give me this error on @IdClass:
The attribute matching the ID class attribute employee does not have the correct type it.my.project.entity.Employee

but the type are correct!

Comment: Try using Integer instead of int.